# Weight must be numeric while trying Circle packing on R GGRAPH

Tags: r, circle-pack, ggraph

i've seen already the topic on the subjet with this issue :

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
edges <- flare$edges
vertices <- flare$vertices
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices=vertices)

ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'circlepack', weight = 'size')
Error in tree_to_hierarchy(graph, direction, sort.by, weight) :
Weight must be numeric
```

Removing the quotations on size doesn't do the trick for me and it's the only solution i found so far !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I ran into the same error as you with the circlepack example. Running the piece of code from @xiaoshi worked for me. 

R version 4.0.3 on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The ggraph package follow the `ggplot2` logic. Are you looking for something like this ?

```
ggraph(graph, 'circlepack',weight=size) + 
    geom_node_circle( n = 50) + 
    coord_fixed()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I have the R version: 4.0.0

And to get the version of `ggraph`, you can do: `packageVersion("ggraph")` and I have 2.0.3.

Comment: edges <- flare$edges
vertices <- flare$vertices

ggraph(graph, 'circlepack',weight=size) + 
    geom_node_circle( n = 50) + 
    coord_fixed()
it return this error :
Erreur : No layout function defined for objects of class function

Comment: I added the graph. Did you expect this graph ? Maybe you have to check the versions (of R, of ggraph, etc.) cf my edits in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so far ! So I have the version 4.0.0 of R (I checked it with the "version" command) and the version 2.0.3 of ggraph and as you talked about ggplot2 I have the version 3.3.0 I don't know if there is any use of it.

I expect this kind of graph but i never saw it with the weighted circle.

Comment: Oh i'm on Windows 10 btw !

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently the problem comes from the fact that values can't worth 0 so i need to add a small value to them or to remove them.